# In JavaScript, should I write a game loop for a turn-based game?

Tags: javascript, game-loop, turn-based

I am using javascript and HTML5 canvas for turn-based games (e.g., checkers, mastermind, minesweeper).

Should I write a fixed-timestep game loop? What are the alternatives?

Comment: Loop only when it is needed. You do not need to redraw the screen when nothing changes in the game world. When it updates, then it is time to redraw it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constantly looping is probably unnecessary for a turn-based game.

If the only time something is going to change is when a player moves, consider using [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) or [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

Here's an approximate setup:

```
var player = {x: 0, y: 0};

//to be executed whenever the player moves
function animate(xDifference, yDifference){
  var pixelsLeftX = xDifference,
      pixelsLeftY = yDifference,
      finishedMoving = false;

  var xInterval = setInterval(function(){
    pixelsLeftX = xDifference > 0 ? pixelsLeftX - 1 : pixelsLeftX + 1;
    if(pixelsLeftX === 0){
      clearInterval(xInterval);
      if(finishedMoving){
        continue()
      }else{
        finishedMoving = true;
      }
    }
  }, 10),
      yInterval = setInterval(function(){
    pixelsLeftY = yDifference > 0 ? pixelsLeftY - 1 : pixelsLeftY + 1;
    if(pixelsLeftX === 0){
      clearInterval(xInterval);
      if(finishedMoving){
        continue()
      }else{
        finishedMoving = true;
      }
    }
  });
}

function continue(){
  //etc
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what I think I should do, but I do have doubts so I asked here first. Will try :)

Comment: It's good to note that although there is no explicit loop structure (`while`/`for`) in this code, the [JavaScript event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) in the background is what causes `setInterval` and `requestAnimationFrame` to fire.